# Objects of HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse in Java?

Tags: servlets

As ***HttpServletRequest And HttpServletResponse*** are Interfaces ,and we Know that in Java we cannot **Instantiate Interfaces**. 
 Then How can we have objects of these 2 in **doGet()** or **doPost()??**

//something here
.......    **doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)**{
//something here
}

Comment: That's just basic Java. Have you never wondered how `List` and `ArrayList` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are provided by the whatever Servlet Container your servlet is running in.  This is a great example of how the Java world uses Interfaces to specify a contract that others follow by providing concrete implementations of those interfaces.

The [Servlet Specification](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) specifies the API for building the environment in which servlets execute, i.e. a *servlet container*.  The servlet specification, as with any standard setting document, doesn't provide an actual software implementation, just the definiton of behaviors, aka the *contract* that implementing software must follow.  Interfaces are used to define this behavior.

These interfaces are provided in the `javax.servlet.*` package space, part of the Java EE -- I think.  Anyhow, it's part of Java.  Folks who wish to provide a Servlet Container implementation must provide their classes that implement these interfaces; the internal details of specific implementations -- tomcat, jetty, etc. -- could vary wildly as long as they comply with the contract of the interface.

Many of the interfaces are implemented by the servlet container itself, but some are meant to be implemented by the application developer.  For instance, if you are writing a webapp you will probably provide your own application specific implementations of the `javax.servlet.Servlet` interface.

At run time, when the servlet container receives a request that maps to your implementation of the Servlet interface, the container will create it's own implementation of the `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`, which represents the incoming request, and this will be passed to your Servlet so it can work whatever it wants to do with that request.  Data available through the request object include request URI, request parameters, etc.

Comment: that's an illustrated and Great explanation. Thanks chad.

Comment: @Rishi  I'm not saying this to toot my own horn . . . but if you think an answer is good, you should upvote it.  The upvoting helps to provide a measure of quality answers, which is very nice to have when you are looking for existing answers to topics you have an interest in.  It's an important part of stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

The implementation classes for these interfaces will be provided by Web Servers (or) Applications Servers.  They will take care to create objects for these interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a Java Web Application using Servlets, your code is deployed onto a Web Container   (e.g. Tomcat) or Application Server (e.g. JBoss). These servers provide their own implementation of those interfaces (i.e. concrete classes that implement those interfaces) and pass instances of them to methods of your servlet.

Comment: something like Server implements HttpServletRequest/Response and passes corresponding request/response object to doGet(),doPost()?

Answer (score 0):

The "servlet container"* provides implementations of these objects. When writing unit tests, you can use a mocking framework such as Mockito to instantiate mock implementations of those interfaces.

*E.g. Google App Engine, Glassfish, Tomcat, JBoss, etc.

Comment: something like Server implements HttpServletRequest/Response and passes corresponding request/response object to doGet(),doPost()?